# Is Blazor a library like React or a framework like Angular?

Tags: angularjs, reactjs, .net-core, blazor, webassembly

Is it possible to get the freedom React gives us to choose our own libraries for each functionality, or do we have follow patterns specified by Blazor ?

---

If not, is it possible to develop a React like library using Mono to run .NET Core on client applications which only deals with the view in MVC ?

Answer (score 1):

Blazor shares some common concepts with React and Angular, it is a UI framework after all.

However, it’s implementation is entirely different. It compiles C# code to run on the .NET runtime within the WebAssembly VM. This code integrates with the browser’s DOM through a JavaScript integration layer.

It is designed to be an entirely self contained UI platform.

If you’re seeking to integrate other JavaScript libraries, it’s unlikely this will work. You can however use other compatible C# libraries with our code.

Comment: Javascript can still be injected in Blazor

Comment: @Anonymous true, but integrating entire js libraries is a long way from using js interop